# pg_fetch_all для несуществующих записей

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Сейчас при запросе к базе данных использую функцию `pg_fetch_all` для сбора всех данных. Но проблема в том, что если я сделаю запрос по значению, которого в таблице не существует, то функция мне ничего не вернёт. Например, я делаю запрос `... IN ('moscow', 'saint-petersburg', 'khabarovsk')`. И функция `pg_fetch_all` вернёт ассоциативный массив длинной в 3 элемента. Но если в таблице нет записи со значением поля `saint-petersburg`, то вернётся массив всего из двух записей, где на втором месте будет расположена информация о Хабаровске. А мне важна последовательность. То есть, нужно, чтобы функция не просто пропускала несуществующие записи, а вставляла вместо них пустой массив - `array()`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Например не использовать `pg_fetch_all`, собсно говоря у вас проблема не в php а в запросе, его нужно изменить для получения желаемого результата, если приведете запрос - попробую исправить

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков запрос простейший - `SELECT * FROM cities_data WHERE page_id IN ('moscow', 'saint-petersburg', 'khabarovsk');`

Comment: Города заранее известны и не меняются от запроса к запросу?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков меняются. Может быть два города, может быть 10 разных городов.

Comment: Тогда смотрите ответ, возможно придется создать пустую таблицу `tmp_data`, не совсем уверен как именно это работает в postgre, ибо в MySQL тех версий что я пользую такого функционала еще нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем уверен в правильности всего запроса целиком но направление точно задаст:

```
with tmp_data (id,value) as 
  (VALUES
    (1,'moscow'),
    (2,'saint-petersburg'),
    (3,'khabarovsk')
  )
Select 
  c.* 
from 
  tmp_data z 
  left join cities_data c on z.value = c.page_id
order by tmp_data.id
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает как часы.